# C++ program with a self-designed class for rational numbers pairs not working as expected

Tags: c++, math, rational-numbers

I have a problem with the code below. It is not performing any function now... neither add nor subtract nor divison nor multiplication.

Any help will be appreciated... I need explanation... so that I can understand it and get over with it :D

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Class Definitions

class RationalNumber
{
public:
     RationalNumber(int, int, int, int);                    
     RationalNumber operator+(RationalNumber);
     RationalNumber operator-(RationalNumber);
     RationalNumber operator*(RationalNumber);
     RationalNumber operator/(RationalNumber);
     RationalNumber operator<(RationalNumber);
     RationalNumber operator>(RationalNumber);
     RationalNumber operator<=(RationalNumber);
     RationalNumber operator>=(RationalNumber);
     RationalNumber operator==(RationalNumber);
     RationalNumber operator!=(RationalNumber);
private:
     int numerator;
     int denominator;
     int numerator2;
     int denominator2;

};  // end RationalNumber class


// RationalNumber class member-function definitions
RationalNumber::RationalNumber(int num, int denom, int num2, int denom2)
{
     numerator = num;
     denominator = denom;
     numerator2 = num2;
     denominator2 = denom2;

//for first fraction
     if (denominator == 0 || denominator < 0)
          cout << "ERROR:Denominator can not be zero or less than zero." << "\n";

     else
          //Reduces the fraction to lowest terms.
     {
          int i = numerator > denominator ? numerator : denominator;

          while(i > 1)
          {
               if(numerator % i == 0 && denominator % i == 0)  
               {
               numerator /= i;
               denominator /= i;
               }
               --i;
          }

     }

     cout << "Simplified fraction one is: " << numerator << " / "
        << denominator << "\n";

//For second fraction
     if (denominator2 == 0 || denominator2 < 0)
          cout << "ERROR:Denominator can not be zero or less than zero" << "\n";
     else
          //Reduces the fraction to lowest terms.
     {
          int j = numerator2 > denominator2 ? numerator2 : denominator2;

          while(j > 1)
          {
               if(numerator2 % j == 0 && denominator2 % j == 0)  
               {
               numerator2 /= j;
               denominator2 /= j;
               }
               --j;
          }

     }
     cout << "Simplified fraction two is: " << numerator2 << " / "
        << denominator2 << "\n";

}

// addition operator
RationalNumber RationalNumber::operator+(RationalNumber a)
{
      RationalNumber temp=RationalNumber(1,2,3,4);
      temp.numerator = numerator + a.numerator;
      temp.denominator = denominator + a.denominator;
      temp.numerator2 = numerator2 + a.numerator2;
      temp.denominator2 = denominator2 + a.denominator2;
      return temp;
}

// subtraction operator
RationalNumber RationalNumber::operator-(RationalNumber a)
{
     RationalNumber temp=RationalNumber(1,2,3,4);
      temp.numerator = numerator - a.numerator;
      temp.denominator = denominator - a.denominator;
      temp.numerator2 = numerator2 - a.numerator2;
      temp.denominator2 = denominator2 - a.denominator2;
      return temp;
}

// multiplication operator
RationalNumber RationalNumber::operator*(RationalNumber a)
{
      RationalNumber temp=RationalNumber(1,2,3,4);
      temp.numerator = numerator * a.numerator;
      temp.denominator = denominator * a.denominator;
      temp.numerator2 = numerator2 * a.numerator2;
      temp.denominator2 = denominator2 * a.denominator2;
      return temp;
}

// division operator
RationalNumber RationalNumber::operator/(RationalNumber a)
{
      RationalNumber temp=RationalNumber(1,2,3,4);
      temp.numerator = numerator / a.numerator;
      temp.denominator = denominator / a.denominator;
      temp.numerator2 = numerator2 / a.numerator2;
      temp.denominator2 = denominator2 / a.denominator2;
      return temp;
}

int main()
{

     int top;
     int bot;
     int top2;
     int bot2;

     cout << "Please enter the Numerator for fraction one: \n";
     cin >> top;
     cout << "Please enter the Denominator for fraction one: \n";
     cin >> bot;
     cout << "Please enter the Numerator for fraction two: \n";
     cin >> top2;
     cout << "Please enter the Denominator for fraction two: \n";
     cin >> bot2;

     RationalNumber A(top, bot, top2, bot2);
     return 0;

}
```

Comment: Aside from the fact that `class()` makes no sense, I fail to see why your class tracks two rational numbers, there are much better ways of finding GCDs, and your addition and subtraction do not make sense arithmetically.

Comment: Note that your division operator does some probably unwanted rounding on the numerators/denominators. Probably it should be implemented in a different way.

Comment: can u fix it... i tried my best

Comment: As a side question: Why does `RationalNumber` need two numerator/denominator pairs?

Comment: because i thought of taking it as two differents rational numbers...

Comment: and it displays two different rational numbers now i want to perform the add function and other functions

Answer (score 4):

By declaring `RationalNumber(int, int, int, int)`, you automatically remove the default constructor, i.e. it is no longer possible to create an instance of your class by invoking a constructor without parameters.

In other words,

`RationalNumber number;`

is no longer possible. You'd need to say

`RationalNumber number(1,2,3,4);`.

If you want to be able to create an instance using a default constructor, then you need to define one in addition to the other constructor:

```
RationalNumber()
{
    // Initialization
}
```

Comment: now the problem is that its not performing any addition nor any other function

Answer (score 1):

Redefine your operators thus:

```
RationalNumber RationalNumber::operator+(RationalNumber a)
{
      return RationalNumber(
          numerator + a.numerator,
          denominator + a.denominator,
          numerator2 + a.numerator2,
          denominator2 + a.denominator2);
}
```

This avoids creating the parameterless temporary that is causing you grief. It also helps the compiler make use of the return-value optimisation (RVO).

Comment: Is `a/b + c/d` equal to `(a+c)/(b+d)`?

Comment: Perhaps I should have looked at the OP's overall logic and corrected it, but I didn't. I'm not even sure why a `RationalNumer` needs four components, so going beyond the stated problem to fix the overall logic would open a can of worms.

Answer (score 1):

I'll take a quick shot at it…

```
#include <utility>

struct ratio {
    int numerator;
    int denominator;

    explicit ratio( int n = 0, int d = 1 )
        : numerator( n ), denominator( d ) { }

    ratio operator - () const {
        ratio x( * this );
        x.numerator = - x.numerator;
        return x;
    }

    ratio operator + () const
        { return *this; }
};

void reduce( ratio &x ) {
    int larger = x.numerator, smaller = x.denominator;
    if ( larger < smaller ) std::swap( larger, smaller );
    while ( int rem = larger % smaller ) {
        larger = smaller;
        smaller = rem;
    }
    x.numerator /= smaller;
    x.denominator /= smaller;
}


ratio &operator += ( ratio &l, ratio const &r ) {
    l.numerator = l.numerator * r.denominator
                + r.numerator * l.denominator;
    l.denominator *= r.denominator;
    reduce( l );
    return l;
}

ratio &operator -= ( ratio &l, ratio const &r )
    { return l += - r; }

ratio &operator *= ( ratio &l, ratio const &r ) {
    l.numerator *= r.numerator;
    l.denominator *= r.denominator;
    reduce( l );
    return l;
}

ratio &operator /= ( ratio &l, ratio const &r ) {
    l.numerator *= r.denominator;
    l.denominator *= r.numerator;
    reduce( l );
    return l;
}
```

Canonical definitions for operators `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`.

Comment: so you want me to change the functions for addition, sub, multiply and divide

Comment: i changed the functions but the problem i m having the addition part is not printing out u get my point...

Comment: neither the subtract nor the divide nor the multiply

Comment: @tiger: This is as close to writing the whole thing as I'll do.

Comment: man.. i tried fixing it and it didnt fix... u have my code.. its not that i didnt putted my effort in it i used ur struct function and everything u told me.. but it just didnt work out..

Comment: @tiger: Can't help you without understanding more. A rational number has one numerator and one denominator, yet your class has two of each. The operations you implement are incorrect. Why? And what difficulty do you have using mine?

Comment: ok.. u know i used ur operators but the problem is functions are not printing out... how will i use these operators and make them print on the screeen....

Answer (score 0):

Your class does not have a constructor that takes zero arguments. Therefore, the following code:

```
class object=class();
```

Is attempting to use a constructor that doesn't exist. You must either write a constructor that takes zero arguments (explicitly or by providing all the default values for another constructor's arguments) or you must provide values upon construction:

```
class object(1, 2, 3, 4);
class object2 = class(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Comment: now its just printing out the fraction part its not performing any addition division nothing help

Comment: @tiger: Piece of advice: place cout statements at the beginning of every function you want to debug, like cout<<"reached here"<<endl; and it'll help a lot when you run the program and see whether that particular function got called or not. Go get 'em tiger! :)

Answer (score 0):

now the problem is ... its not performing any addition nor any other function... the program is running perfect but somehow i get the additon and other functions to work

thanks

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Class Definitions

class RationalNumber
{
public:
     RationalNumber(int, int, int, int);                    
     RationalNumber operator+(RationalNumber);
     RationalNumber operator-(RationalNumber);
     RationalNumber operator*(RationalNumber);
     RationalNumber operator/(RationalNumber);
     RationalNumber operator<(RationalNumber);
     RationalNumber operator>(RationalNumber);
     RationalNumber operator<=(RationalNumber);
     RationalNumber operator>=(RationalNumber);
     RationalNumber operator==(RationalNumber);
     RationalNumber operator!=(RationalNumber);
private:
     int numerator;
     int denominator;
     int numerator2;
     int denominator2;

};  // end RationalNumber class


// RationalNumber class member-function definitions
RationalNumber::RationalNumber(int num, int denom, int num2, int denom2)
{
     numerator = num;
     denominator = denom;
     numerator2 = num2;
     denominator2 = denom2;

//for first fraction
     if (denominator == 0 || denominator < 0)
          cout << "ERROR:Denominator can not be zero or less than zero." << "\n";

     else
          //Reduces the fraction to lowest terms.
     {
          int i = numerator > denominator ? numerator : denominator;

          while(i > 1)
          {
               if(numerator % i == 0 && denominator % i == 0)  
               {
               numerator /= i;
               denominator /= i;
               }
               --i;
          }

     }

     cout << "Simplified fraction one is: " << numerator << " / "
        << denominator << "\n";

//For second fraction
     if (denominator2 == 0 || denominator2 < 0)
          cout << "ERROR:Denominator can not be zero or less than zero" << "\n";
     else
          //Reduces the fraction to lowest terms.
     {
          int j = numerator2 > denominator2 ? numerator2 : denominator2;

          while(j > 1)
          {
               if(numerator2 % j == 0 && denominator2 % j == 0)  
               {
               numerator2 /= j;
               denominator2 /= j;
               }
               --j;
          }

     }
     cout << "Simplified fraction two is: " << numerator2 << " / "
        << denominator2 << "\n";

}

// addition operator
RationalNumber RationalNumber::operator+(RationalNumber a)
{
      RationalNumber temp=RationalNumber(1,2,3,4);
      temp.numerator = numerator + a.numerator;
      temp.denominator = denominator + a.denominator;
      temp.numerator2 = numerator2 + a.numerator2;
      temp.denominator2 = denominator2 + a.denominator2;
      return temp;
}

// subtraction operator
RationalNumber RationalNumber::operator-(RationalNumber a)
{
      RationalNumber temp=RationalNumber(1,2,3,4);
      temp.numerator = numerator - a.numerator;
      temp.denominator = denominator - a.denominator;
      temp.numerator2 = numerator2 - a.numerator2;
      temp.denominator2 = denominator2 - a.denominator2;
      return temp;
}

// multiplication operator
RationalNumber RationalNumber::operator*(RationalNumber a)
{
      RationalNumber temp=RationalNumber(1,2,3,4);
      temp.numerator = numerator * a.numerator;
      temp.denominator = denominator * a.denominator;
      temp.numerator2 = numerator2 * a.numerator2;
      temp.denominator2 = denominator2 * a.denominator2;
      return temp;
}

// division operator
RationalNumber RationalNumber::operator/(RationalNumber a)
{
      RationalNumber temp=RationalNumber(1,2,3,4);
      temp.numerator = numerator / a.numerator;
      temp.denominator = denominator / a.denominator;
      temp.numerator2 = numerator2 / a.numerator2;
      temp.denominator2 = denominator2 / a.denominator2;
      return temp;
}

int main()
{

     int top;
     int bot;
     int top2;
     int bot2;

     cout << "Please enter the Numerator for fraction one: \n";
     cin >> top;
     cout << "Please enter the Denominator for fraction one: \n";
     cin >> bot;
     cout << "Please enter the Numerator for fraction two: \n";
     cin >> top2;
     cout << "Please enter the Denominator for fraction two: \n";
     cin >> bot2;

     RationalNumber A(top, bot, top2, bot2);
     return 0;

}
```

Comment: Don't add an answer. Edit your question instead.

Comment: i edited it sir can you look at it now thanks alot really appreciate the effort and u guys helping me